# How to display an error from action without redirection?

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4

In the action corresponding to the added form, I want to display an error above the form. But when I write:

```
if("1" != $error)
{
   $this->redirect('@domaine'); 
}
else 
{
   $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', "A domain with the same name already exists.");
}
```

nothing happend.

But if I redirect user, it works, the error message displays. But I don't want. 
I want to stay on the form and display the error message above the form.

Comment: Can you show us a var_dump from the $error variable?

Comment: `var_dump($error) => string(1) "1"`

Comment: Is the flash displayed in the form template?

Answer (score 0):

if it has nothing to do with server then you can use jquery which will be fast and more flexible to customize.